# How i can count item in one column with SQL statement

Tags: sql, database

I have one DB (programming is with Delphi) , and I want to count an item in one column.

For example, the table like this:

```
column1    | column2
-----------+-------------
employee1  | employee2
employee3  | employee1
employee1  | employee1
employee2  | employee3
```

I want to count employees in that columns, for example, how i can get result `2`, from `count( employee1)` in `column1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A standard SQL aggregate that can be used in all database engines.

This gives "count per employee value"

```
SELECT
   column1, COUNT(*)
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   column1
```

For employee1 only

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   column1 = 'employee1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    sum(
        case when column1 = 'employee1' then 1
        else 0 end
    )
from table;
```

Comment: ..wouldn't a WHERE clause be simpler?